# Kotlin binary compatibility validator plugin $stable field

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Hi every one I am using Kotlin binary compatibility validator plugin in my project, after adding compose into my project the compiler adds a field called stable this is causing Kotlin binary compatibility validator plugin to complain is there a way to ignore this field since it is not part of the public API practically speaking.
example of the the plugin output is

```
 public static final field $stable I
```